# Is this a correct (intended) usage of MooseX::Getopt?

Tags: perl, moose

Is this a correct (intended) use of [MooseX::Getopt](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Getopt)?  The documentation doesn't have a lot of examples.  The code works, but I don't know if this was the intended usage model.

```
package AppOpt {
    use Moose;
    use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;
    use namespace::autoclean;

    with 'MooseX::Getopt';

    enum 'ReportType', [qw( activityByEvent activityByDate final )];
    enum 'FormatType', [qw( text pretty html )];

    has report => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', required => 1 );

    has verbose => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'Bool', default => 0 );

    has format => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', default => "text" );

    __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
}

package main;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $opt = AppOpt->new_with_options();

printf("original \@ARGV = [%s]\n\n", join(' ', @ARGV));

# Please ignore this tasteless inspection of the object guts. -E
for my $k (keys(%{$opt})) {
    unless($k =~ /(usage|ARGV|extra_argv)/) {
    printf("%s => %s\n", $k, $$opt{$k});
    }
}
exit(0);
```

Specifically: Are the options intended to be their own Class?  I can't be sure from the docs.

Also, would it be appropriate to use `BUILD` to further validate the options?

This may sound like more than one question, but I don't mean it to be.  I've run with other modules before only to find that I misunderstood how they were intended to be used.

Comment: With `%{$opt}` you're directly inspecting the internals of a Moose object. I'm pretty sure that's not correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "*Are the options intended to be their own object?*"?

Comment: Oh! `AppOpt` is not supposed to be an "options class", it's the application class. You might want to give it a `main` method and use it as `AppOpt->new_with_options->main();`. All `MooseX::Getopt` gives you is a constructor that can initialize attributes not from its constructor arguments, but from command line arguments. Is that what you mean? (If you don't have an "application class" or don't know why you'd use one, you probably don't need MooseX::Getopt.)

Comment: @melpomene Yes, that was what I was trying to ask.  I don't have an "application class", but I do need to deal with options.  While I've only been moosing for about a week, I like it.  I just wanted to make sure I was using this module correctly, and it sound like, "no, not really".  Right?

Comment: I know plundering the `%{$opt}` object is in bad form.  I just needed to quickly check the guts to make sure it was doing what I thought it was.  It seems weird to use this for an application class without traits.  Wouldn't that expose all of the application guts to the command line otherwise?

Comment: @ErikBennett There is no "using this module"; you can just add that "role" to a class, and -- bingo, now there are command-line options for the program that uses that class.  That's the intent of it.  (There are a few methods/accessors to query the state of the command-line options, as well.)  Of course, it's probably a good idea to use it thoughtfully, to bundle desired command-line options for the program.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't mean `use`, but rather me employing it...  In any case, I think I understand.  My usage of it above is not the way the author intended for it to be deployed.  This is important news!  Thanks, again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The role [MooseX::Getopt](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Getopt) sets up command line options for attributes (except for those starting with `_`) of the class it is used with (consumed by). It is not intended to be "used" on its own.

So you write a class `AppOpt`, with attribute `report`, and when you include `MooseX::Getopt` role you can call the program with `--report...`, where option details are set by inferring as much as possible about the attribute from its class.  That's it.  You get command-line options.

A few accessors are provided, that one can use to inspect what happened on the command line, listed in your regex. But use them as accessors (methods), not by directly poking at the object.

Comment: The way I was using it was slightly... off-color.  I've incorporated the `MooseX::Getopt` into a more general `Configuration.pm` module, which gets information from defaults, an init file, and the command line.

Comment: @ErikBennett OK, thanks for clarification. That doesn't sound bad or off-handed to me, either.  The role provides for atttribute initialization via command-line, and i don't think that there's a very specific intent about it; whichever way you find that useful. (Packaging that capability in a config-type module sounds about right? Apart from the very basic use, to just stick it in the main/application class. Perhaps that'd be the "main intent," merely since it's easiest.)